# Issue jumping to a row in a grid panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using Extjs 4.2. I have a grid panel which has >1000 rows and it has multiselect turned on.

When I click a button I want to select and move to row 20 using the following:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(20, false, true);
grid.getView().getNode(20).scrollIntoView();
```

This works fine if I am near row 20 but otherwise it correctly selects row 20 but it does not jump to row 20 and I get the error:     TypeError: grid.getView(...).getNode(...) is undefined

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please put your code in to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you using [buffered rendering](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer) for your grid? And which precise version of Ext4.2?

Comment: I'm using 4.2.2. I am using buffered rendering- is that an issue?

Comment: Thanks Rixo for asking about buffered rendering- my grid uses this and I was able to find an example that showed me how to jump to a row outside of my buffered rows- my answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rixo put me on the correct path asking about buffered grids.

I found this example which has it all: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html

This is the line that allows me to jump to row 20:

```
grid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(20, true);
```

Comment: It is recommend in 6.5 to use the ensureVisible method of the grid.  
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-ensureVisible

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no such Node when you are far away from it, as the GridView simply does not destroys the HTML element because of performance issues. You could use [gridView.focusNode(record)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-method-focusRow) for that instead:

```
var record = gridView.getStore().getById(20);
gridView.focusNode(record);
```

And after that focus select the record:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(record);
```

Comment: I used 'grid.getView().focusRow(20)' and 'grid.getView().focusNode(20);' with the same result- it won't scroll if I am more than a page and a bit away. The only difference is that I am not getting an error. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Method `focusNode()` expects a record, not a number. See my updated answer.

Comment: Try the inverse: first focusNode and then select it.

Comment: I got a record that I selected and then tried to focus it: 
    grid.getSelectionModel().select(20, false, true); 
    var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
    grid.getView().focusNode(record);</code> 
This gave me the same issue as before. Also I used a delay on focusRow: 'grid.getSelectionModel().select(20, false, true); grid.getView().focusRow(20, 100);' But same isssue

Comment: Hi Andrei, I put a getSelectionModel before and after I got the row and no joy.

Answer (score 0):

First Select your record using:

```
var rec = grid.store.findRecord('id',rowId);
```

Select the record using :

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(  rec  );
```

Focus the record using :

```
grid.getView().focusRow(  );
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem selecting the row. 
The issue I am having is with scrolling to the row in question. 
focusRow(20) doesn't work when I am more than a page and a bit away. 
The same is the case for focusNode(rec)

Comment: Once you select the record **grid.getView().focusRow(  );** will automatically focus selected record.